# Laravel Model Collections with multiple tables and where statement

Tags: laravel, collections, model

I need to get data from 2 tables using Laravel models and collections. I can do that with :

```
$results = Tasks::with('resource')->get();
```

how can i add a where statement to this? (I am trying to get all tasks where deleted=0;

```
//I tried $results = Tasks::with('resource')->get()->where('tasks.deleted', '!=','1');
```

with no luck

Comment: what about $results = Tasks::where('deleted', '!=',1)->with('resource')->get();

Comment: $results = Tasks::query()->withWhereHas('resource',function($query){
        $query->where('deleted', '!=',1);
    })->get();   if you want ot filter resource data

Comment: Order of operations matters. `->where(...)->get()` (correct) will perform database-level filtering, while `->get()->where(...)` (generally incorrect, but necessary sometimes) will perform PHP-level filtering, which, depending on how many rows are in your table, can be incredibly poor performing. Also @JohnLobo you generally don't need `::query()`; it's implied on most `Model` calls. `Task::withWhereHas(...)` is valid (and in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads-with-relationship-existence)

Comment: @TimLewis ::query() i use to get autocomplete laravel methods in phpstrom so .then will remove generally

Comment: @JohnLobo Oh right, that's the use-case scenario for that (I don't use PHPStorm). Carry on! 